# Travelling Salesman Problem using weighted graph (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7

I am trying to implement the Travelling Salesman Problem using weighted graph.

```
import random


def randomSolution(tsp):
    cities = list(range(len(tsp)))
    solution = []

    for i in range(len(tsp)):
        randomCity = cities[random.randint(0, len(cities) - 1)]
        solution.append(randomCity)
        cities.remove(randomCity)
    return solution


def routeLength(tsp, solution):
    routeLength = 0
    for i in range(len(solution)):
        routeLength += tsp[solution[i - 1]][solution[i]]
    return routeLength


def getNeighbours(solution):
    neighbours = []
    for i in range(len(solution)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(solution)):
            neighbour = solution.copy()
            neighbour[i] = solution[j]
            neighbour[j] = solution[i]
            neighbours.append(neighbour)
    return neighbours


def getBestNeighbour(tsp, neighbours):
    bestRouteLength = routeLength(tsp, neighbours[0])
    bestNeighbour = neighbours[0]
    for neighbour in neighbours:
        currentRouteLength = routeLength(tsp, neighbour)
        if currentRouteLength < bestRouteLength:
            bestRouteLength = currentRouteLength
            bestNeighbour = neighbour
    return bestNeighbour, bestRouteLength


def hillClimbing(tsp):
    currentSolution = randomSolution(tsp)
    currentRouteLength = routeLength(tsp, currentSolution)
    neighbours = getNeighbours(currentSolution)
    bestNeighbour, bestNeighbourRouteLength = getBestNeighbour(tsp, neighbours)

    while bestNeighbourRouteLength < currentRouteLength:
        currentSolution = bestNeighbour
        currentRouteLength = bestNeighbourRouteLength
        neighbours = getNeighbours(currentSolution)
        bestNeighbour, bestNeighbourRouteLength = getBestNeighbour(
            tsp, neighbours)

    return currentSolution, currentRouteLength


tsp = [
    ('A', 'B', 9),
    ('A', 'C', 3),
    ('A', 'D', 2),
    ('A', 'E', 10),
    ('B', 'C', 8),
    ('B', 'D', 7),
    ('B', 'E', 5),
    ('C', 'D', 4),
    ('C', 'E', 11),
    ('D', 'E', 6)
]

print(hillClimbing(tsp))
```

Here A, B, C, D, E are nodes and the third parameter in tsp is the weight of that node.
e.g: to go from node A to B, the weight is 9.
The problem is that when I use TSP with the cost it works fine.

```
tsp = [
    [923, 529, 297, 693, 907],
    [542, 693, 401, 280, 785],
    [272, 470, 988, 509, 592],
    [913, 831, 740, 858, 451]
]
```

But with graphs it generates error which looks like:

> ```
> routeLength += tsp[solution[i - 1]][solution[i]]
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
> ```

Comment: I assume your code represent a heuristic, which hopefully will return a good tour, as opposed to a solution that is guaranteed to be optimal? Correct?

Comment: The graph is a one-dimensional array of tuples, but the code expects `tsp` to be a two-dimensional array of numbers. So when the python interpreter reaches the line `routeLength += tsp[solution[i - 1]][solution[i]]` it takes the first index as an index into the array of tuples, and the second index as the member number. The member number must be 0, 1, or 2 for a tuple with three members. So long story short, if you're going to switch from the 2D array of numbers to the 1D array of tuples, you need to redesign and rewrite the code.

Comment: In addition to the above issues, I believe that the initial starting solution, just like any solution, must represent a valid sequence of links between cities. For example,  the sequence ('A', 'B', 9), ('C', 'D', 4) is not allowed by the graph but randomSolution() does not attempt to address this.

Comment: Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.